# Is the KDF pbkdf2 included in the openssl suite?

Tags: key-derivation, openssl

I'm trying to encrypt a file using DES in CBC mode but when I try to specify the key derivation function it tells me my command is wrong. It only fails when I try specify the KDF and works when I don't. This is the command i'm trying to use - openssl enc -des-cbc -pbkdf2 -in test.txt -out test.bin -pass pass:test

This command is taken directly from my reference so why does it not pick up the KDF? Is it because i'm using the wrong version of openssl (LibreSSL 2.6.4) or do I have to manually add pbkdf2? If so how do I?

Comment: You're actually asking about the _commandline utility_ `openssl`, which is a very different thing from the OpenSSL (or derivative like LibreSSL) _suite_. OpenSSL _library_ has included PBKDF2 for about 20 years, and has supported it for PKCS8 key files, although as ZT answers using it in commandline `enc` is very recent. Also to be clear even if you use PBKDF2 and a good password, anything encrypted this century in single-DES is easily broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LibreSSL enc docs: https://man.openbsd.org/openssl.1#ENC

OpenSSL enc docs for version 1.1.1 : https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html

Both support pbkdf2. I am kinda surprised LibreSSL still supports DES, I would not support it. Can you paste the exact error you're getting?

Edit:

The [changelog of libressl](https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/blob/master/ChangeLog) says pbkdf2 support was added in version 2.9.1 (latest current version).

Comparing the openssl 1.1.1 man page above with the [openssl 1.1.0 enc man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man1/enc.html), I see pbkdf2 support was added in version 1.1.1 (latest current stable version).

You're trying to use a very new feature.

Comment: Hamish$ openssl enc -des-cbc -pbkdf2 -in ciphers.txt -out test.bin -pass pass:test
usage: enc -ciphername [-AadePp] [-base64] [-bufsize number] [-debug]

Comment: It basically just prints out the usage as if the command is malformed

Comment: Output of `openssl version -a`?

Comment: LibreSSL 2.6.4
built on: date not available
platform: information not available
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: information not available
OPENSSLDIR: "/private/etc/ssl"

Comment: I'm gonna try using a different distribution of openssl on vm fusion maybe that will change something.

Comment: Yeah so I just tried on linux with openssl 1.1.0g using the same command, this time it just tells me: enc: Unknown cipher pbkdf2

Comment: @Hamish I edited my answer.